# How do I update my coordinates instead of having them overlap?

Tags: javascript

I have a program that writes the coordinates of where my mouse is on a given canvas. the problem I'm having is that it won't update them, but only overlaps every time I move my mouse. I'm not sure how to fix this after long times of thought...

```
/* This program displays the x and y
 * coordinates in a label on the screen
 * and updates when the mouse moves */

var text;

function start(){
    mouseMoveMethod(coords);
} 

function coords(e){
    var text = new Text(e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() , "30pt Arial");
    text.setPosition(0,30);
    add(text);
    text.setText(e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());
}
```

Comment: it'd be very good if you post all your code, and better if you post it on a code snippet. cheers!

Comment: if I'm not wrong, the issue you're facing is drop and drag the canvas, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call coords, it creates a new Text and overlays it on all the others.
You want to reuse something and update it.

Try this instead (fleshed out appropriately):

```
<div id=coordsdiv style="position:absolute;left:0;top: 30"> </div>

<script>  
function coords(e)
{c = document.getElementById("coordsdiv");
 c.innerHTML = "(" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")";
}
</script>
```